# How to find a Android Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Currently, I read some books talking about possible memory leaks in Android. However, is there any way(tool/technique) to detect memory leak rather than using experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect Memory Leaks

### Adding LeakCanary to your project

In your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
  testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

In your `Application` class:

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {
  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```

In your `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".ExampleApplication"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) for this.  It's a helpful tool and fairly simple to setup:

### Getting started

In your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
  testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

In your `Application` class:

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {
  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```